# Promise combine stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I want read big file line by line and insert the data in DB store.
My functon return a Promise inside it created stream, and resolve it when event `stream.on('end')` was invoked, but it is not I really want, because in `stream.on('data')` it produce `Promise.map()` on each line, and I want to be sure, that all insertion ops completed before `resolve()` invoked. How I can produce right chain in this case?

```
    var loadFromFile = (options) => new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let stream = fs.createReadStream(options.filePath, {
          flags: 'r',
        });

        stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
            /* process data chunk to string Array */  
            Promise.map(lines, (line) => {
            /* process and insert each line here */
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
                reject(err);
            });
          });

          stream.on('end', () => {
              if (someBuisnessLogicCheckHere) {
                reject('Invalid data was found in file');
              }
              resolve(); // Here I am not sure, that all inserts for each chunk in Promise.map was completed
          });
    });
```

Comment: You need code and to be alot clearer then this.

Comment: add some code, its simple, as I describe early

Comment: @Dmitriy: And yet, quoting it let me answer your question. Code is worth 1024 words!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be sure you don't resolve until all of the promises in the mapping operation have resolved, wait for the promise that `Promise.map` returns; see comments:

```
var loadFromFile = (options) => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let stream = fs.createReadStream(options.filePath, {
        flags: 'r',
    });
    let promises = [];                                 // Array of promises we'll wait for

    stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
        promises.push(                                 // Remember this promise
            Promise.map(lines, (line) => {
                /* process and insert each line here */
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            })
        );
    });

    stream.on('end', () => {
        if (someBuisnessLogicCheckHere) {
            reject('Invalid data was found in file');
        }
        Promise.all(promises).then(() => { resolve()}); // Wait for it before resolving
    });
});
```

Note that I didn't just do `Promise.all(promises).then(resolve);`, because that will pass an array of resolutions to `resolve`, which your original code didn't share with the caller.

If there's a possibility the array will get quite large while being filled with most already-resolved promises, you could remove them proactively as they resolve and only wait on the ones that are left at the end.

Comment: thanks, I try to do same, but one question here: I want read and insert data simultaneously, in this case jobs in promises Array will be wait before read file was end and invoke "Promise.all" func ? I am new in promises, sorry if it stupid question

Comment: @Dmitriy: No, they won't wait. The promise is just a notification mechanism. The work inside the promise happens regardless of whether anyone's watching it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to process the file with automated mechanisms of pause/resume in the pipe method, take a look at [scramjet](http://scramjet.io).

Your example would look much clearer, see:

```
var loadFromFile = (options) => 
    fs.createReadStream(options.filePath, {
        flags: 'r',
    })
    .split(/\r?\n/) 
         // split by line by regex
    .parse((line) => aPromiseReturningFunction(line))
         // will wait until promises are resolved
    .map((data) => doSomeAsyncAndReturnPromise(data))      
         // will wait as above
    .accumulate((acc, resolved) => acc.push(resolved), [])
    .then((arr) => {
         if (someBuisnessLogicCheckHere) {
              return Promise.reject('Invalid data was found in file');
         }
         // Here all your items are saved (i.e. all Promises resolved)
     });
});
```