# async csv To JSON data output in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a terrible misunderstanding with promises in nodejs.
I have a function in a module to convert CSV to JSON:

```
const URL_01 = `${__dirname}/URL/some_CSV.csv`;

const fs = require('fs'),
  Converter = require('csvtojson').Converter,
  converter = new Converter({}),

  convertToJson = function(file) {
    return new Promise( (res, rej) => {
      converter.on("end_parsed", (jsonData) => {
        if(!jsonData){
          rej("CSV to JSON conversion failed!")
        }
        res(jsonData);
      });
      fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(converter);
    });
  };

export default convertToJson;
```

Then I need to launch function convertToJson with CSVfile_URL in a server.js and save it to mongo db, now no data is output:

```
    app.get('/all', async (req, res) => {
  const data = await convertToJson( URL_01 );
  res.send(data);
});
```

Who could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple issues:

1. You're mixing ES2015 module syntax with CommonJS syntax which won't work.
2. Doesn't look like you're using `csvjson` correctly based on the documentation for the module [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson).

With that said, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254448/promise-combine-stream) answer, something like this may work (untested):

```
const fs = require('fs')
const csv = require('csvtojson')

const URL_01 = `${__dirname}/URL/some_CSV.csv`;

module.exports = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const promises = []
  csv()
    .fromFile(URL_01)
    .on('json', converted => promsies.push(Promise.resolve(converted)))
    .on('done', error => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error)
        return
      }
    Promise.all(promises).then(convertedResults => resolve(convertedResults))
  })
})
```

Comment: what if one is passing the file from client side to server? would i just put in the variable data inside fromFile?

Comment: No. `fromFile` takes a path to the location of the file on disk. If you're trying to process a file from client side upload, I think `.fromStream()` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('yourFile.csv')

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    csv(options)
        .fromStream(readStream)
        .subscribe(json=>{
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                resolve(json)
            })
        })
        .on('header', header => {
            log(`Converting CSV to JSON - headers: ${headers}`)
        })
         .on('data', async data => {
                // data is a buffer object
                const jsonStr = data.toString('utf8')
                log(`Converting CSV to JSON - Current Line: ${jsonStr}`)
                await fs.appendFile(editDumb, jsonStr)
            })
        .on('done', () => {
            log('Finished converting CSV to JSON')
            resolve()
        })
        .on('error', e => {
            throw new BaseError(`Error while converting CSV to JSON - Error: ${e}`)
        })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use a ready-made `async-csv` package from NPM. This will be as simple as:

```
const csv = require('async-csv');
let parsedObject = await csv.parse(csvFileAsString);
```

Comment: not working. I dont think async-csv can use await